# RAILS: can't modify frozen SystemStackError (FrozenError) after upgradeing to Ruby 2.5.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error appears after upgrading from Ruby 2.2 to latest `Ruby 2.5.3` for my Rails 4.2.0 app. Should I use older version of Ruby?

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The factory_girl gem is deprecated. Please upgrade to factory_bot. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/v4.9.0/UPGRADE_FROM_FACTORY_GIRL.md for further instructions. (called from <top (required)> at C:/D/code/rails_proj/cis/config/application.rb:7)
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
```

Traceback:

```
    DEPRECATION WARNING: The factory_girl gem is deprecated. Please upgrade to factory_bot. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/v4.9.0/UPGRADE_FROM_FACTORY_GIRL.md for further instructions. (called from <top (required)> at C:/D/code/rails_proj/cis/config/application.rb:7)
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
        15: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        14: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
         9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
         8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
         7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:125:in `print_boot_information'
         6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/server.rb:291:in `server'
         5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
         4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rack-1.6.11/lib/rack/handler.rb:90:in `try_require'
         3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
         2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
         1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/d (LoadError)
```

Here is the bin/rails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'      <==caused error above
```

Comment: what is the actual stack trace? Please post. Also I would not recommend 4.2 and 2.5 in combination. The [travis.yml](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/.travis.yml) only runs up to `2.4.4` and I think even that is pushing it

Comment: I have app with rails `4.1.8` and the most recent ruby version I got running is  `2.3.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to either [upgrade to the latest version of Rails 4.2](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/4.2.11) or use a Ruby version older than 2.3 ([introduction of frozen_string_literal pragma](https://wyeworks.com/blog/2015/12/1/immutable-strings-in-ruby-2-dot-3)). If neither of these work, look at the stacktrace and try to see if you're trying to modify an object that has been frozen.